# Can a JS script block a whole server? If so, how can I possibly get rid of this attack?

Tags: javascript, jquery, http-status-code-404

We are using MySQL db and Apache as our server. All of our project folders are affected by a particular script called "y.js/a.js" which is blocking our whole .js files and sits before  that triggers 404 error. The URL it all refers to is [https://tom.verybeatifulantony.com/a.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fYvH.png) (or) [https://tom.verybeatifulantony.com/y.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fYvH.png). It calls this same js files in each and every project.

The following are the screenshots below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: A script that fails to load shouldn't block the page from loading. You can see in the DevTools that it continued loading other scripts like jQuery.

Comment: If you didn't put that script into your pages, it means your site has been hacked. You need to reinstall everything because there might be other things affected.

Comment: @Barmar If it's been hacked, how should I prevent this in future?

Comment: You need to improve the security of your server. Without knowing how they got in, it's impossible to be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

we have noticed this script being inserted in HTML and PHP files in many of our hosted sites as well. this appears to be some sort of malicious code.  you will need to remove this script from every file where the script has been inserted.

on Linux, go to the root directory of where all your sites are located, or to the root of each site and execute the following to get a list of all files infected.

```
sudo grep --include=\*.{js,html,htm,php} -rnw '.' -e "tom.verybeatifulantony.com"
```

Comment: It's not a solution. You have a hacked plugin, which will infect these files again and again

Comment: True this does not correct the root cause, but does allow you to remove the malware. The prevent reinfection, you need to locate the vulnerable plugins and remove or update them, ensure only needed ports are open on your server, made sure no strange new user accounts exist on your site or server, change your current users passwords.

Answer (score 1):

If you have not read the article on Wordfence security site, check it out. Google "wordfence multiple-attack-campaigns-targeting-recent-plugin-vulnerabilities"
It mentions some compromised WordPress plugins that have been used by attackers to compromise websites using vulnerable plugins. This includes adding back-doors and grabbing administrative rights to the websites. One of the many malicious domains mentioned in the article is tom.verybeatifulantony.com

The article unfortunately, does not describe a full cleanup method if your site has been attacked (maybe because they offer a paid clean-up service?).

So my suggestion is to install the free version of the Wordfence plugin and use its scan function to check for security problems on your site. Other security plugins might also help but I have no experience of these other plugins. I would also change the admin username and password and check if other admin users have been added and delete them if you don't recognise them. Or change their passwords. Of course, update all your plugins to the latest versions too.

To those with many sites to administer, Wordfence offers Wordfence Central where many sites can be managed from one central dashboard.

PS I am not in any way connected with Wordfence. I use their free plugin and they send me regular security updates related to WordPress vulnerabilties, which includes naming plugins that have been compromised.

Answer (score 1):

Witam
źródło tego  jest w luce wtyczki Hello Doly, a raczej wtyczce niezaktualizowanej w której jest luka stosowana w Cms Wordpress katalog wp-hello-plugin. Obejżyj zawartość usuń plik-u mnie "mn" wyczyść pliki index.php i index.html z wpisu : "https://tom.verybeatifulantony.com/y.js'>" i będzie ok

Comment: Please use English for your answer

Comment: It might be correct. I doubted that. We are currently handling one wordpress project and installed so many plugins. You may be right.. Whatever language, use translator, he loves to contribute. encourage him @Roeland

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the link and save it, i did the same and it works.

Comment: But how could I do it for more than 40 projects?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that whatever vulnerability this is also changes write permissions on the infected files - remember to change that after editing the files.

Also, infected files seem to be index.php and index.html

Answer (score -1):

Our files are affected, too. Where or how do I have to execute the following you wrote?

sudo grep --include=*.{js,html,htm,php} -rnw '.' -e "tom.verybeatifulantony.com"

Would you be so kind and give me a manual....

Comment: Answers are not really the place to be asking more questions...